# Pre-populate the Form field by formBackingObject method using standard html code in spring web

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I just trying to pre-populate the form field in user form by **formBackingObject**.
I am using simple html code not spring tags to create the field.

Actually I'v tried with spring tag but spring tags for input filed is not working so I moved to simple html code but spring tags works for `<form:form action=**>` but not for `<form:input path="name" />`

I'v check taglib import segment but its fine and I don't understand if `<form:form />`
is working then why `<form:input path="name" />` is not working.

I'm describing this because somewhere and someone from StackOverflow said that for getting benefit of **formBackingObject**, I'v to use spring tags for input field but in my case its not working.

Here I'm considering of **formBackingObject** only for pre-populating form field that what my question title suggest. Anyhow I'v to do it soon.
I'v gone through about 30-40 page link for finding of this solution but .....

I need a very simple example of it where jsp field getting value of object that is return by **formBackingObject**

***I'm not familiar with annotation***

*Here is my tried and failed example*

> contact_form.jsp

```
<form:form action="edit.htm" commandName="contact"  method="POST">

Name:<input type="text" name="name" value=${contact.name} /><br>

Address:<input type="text" name="address" value=${contact.address}/><br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit"/><br>
```

> EditController

```
public class EditController extends SimpleFormController {

private static Contact cont = new Contact();
static {
    cont.setAddress("aaa");
    cont.setName("bbb");
}
@Override
protected void doSubmitAction(Object command) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("In do submit method");
}


@Override
protected Object formBackingObject(HttpServletRequest request)
        throws Exception {
    System.out.println("In FormBackingObject");
    return cont;
}
```

> spring-servlet.xml

```
<bean id="/edit.htm" class="tryPack7.EditController">
    <property name="CommandClass" value="tryPack7.Contact" />
    <property name="commandName" value="contact" />
    <property name="formView" value="contact_form" />
    <property name="successView" value="success" />
</bean>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have specified handler mapping in your confog xml file:
Make sure you have jsp on similar lines as below:

```
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
    <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Sample Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form:form commandName="contact" method="POST">
            <table>
                  <tr >
                    <td>Name:<form:input path="name"/></td>
                 </tr> 
                 <tr >
                    <td>Address:<form:input path="address"/></td>
                 </tr> 
                 <tr>
                    <td colspan="3"><input type="submit"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </form:form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Also, rather than using static way, I would suggest to initialize contact form in formBackingObject as shown below:

```
    public class EditController extends SimpleFormController { 
        public ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)            
        throws ServletException, IOException 
        {        
            Contact contact=(Contact)formBackingObject(request);
            return new ModelAndView("contact_form","contact",contact);    
        }

        public Object formBackingObject(HttpServletRequest req)
        {   
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setAddress("aaa");
            contact.setName("bbb");
            return contact;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'v used what you have written for jsp file but its no working, Its raising an exception 'java.lang.IllegalStateException'. and there is no issue of initialization of contact form.

Comment: Can you post full exception stacktrace.

Comment: its too large to post but I'm posting some piece of it.[An exception occurred processing JSP page /pages/contact_form.jsp at line 28

25:     <form:form action="edit.htm" commandName="contact"  method="POST">
26:  <table>
27:                   <tr >
28:                     <td>Name:<form:input path="name"/></td>
29:                  </tr> 
30:                  <tr >
31:                     <td>Address:<form:input path="address"/></td>


Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'contact' available as request attrib

Comment: See my edit to handleRequestInternal method : return new ModelAndView("contact_form","contact",contact);

Comment: Its not solve my issue it return back to the same page the filled object. I want to populate field at the initial page before doing any event or rendering to another page.

Comment: For prefilled contact object when SimpleFormController is used, you need to override formBackingObject method as shown above before rendering the page. If you don't want the form to be prefilled, don't override formBackingObject with populated Contact object.BTW you are having contact in static way, which will be filled always.